# Getting error with If-else using null

Tags: java

I'm a beginner Java student and trying to get this code to show second JOptionPane if the number chosen is  negative or 0.  The second JOption isn't appearing if I choose 0 or a negative number.  I suspect it has something to do with the "if(result != null)".  I've tried using different operands and values and keep getting  the bad operand types error.  I would like to stick with the if-else statement because that's where we are at the moment in class.

```
public static void calculateR()   
{            
 String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter how much money you can save annually.");  
 if(result != null)
 {
   saveAmount = Double.parseDouble(result);
 }
   else
 {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pick a number greater than 0!");
 }
```

Comment: Share the stacktrace.

Comment: Are you expecting `if(result != null)` to check whether the number is greater than 0? Because it doesn't do that.

Comment: @DiogoSantana Can you give me some direction on what I can use in it's place.

Comment: We need the stacktrace you getting to help you.

Comment: @DiogoSantana, like the code is no errors it just doesn't show second Pane when I enter 0 or negative num but when I change operands I'm getting (bad operand for binary operator) I understand that's trying to use math on a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some code logic like this:

```
saveAmount = 0.0;
String result;
while (saveAmount <= 0) {
    result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter how much money you can save annually.")
    if (result != null) {
        saveAmount = Double.parseDouble(result);
        if (saveAmount < 0.0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pick a number greater than 0!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as answered.

Comment: the "Pick a number greater than 0!" pane isn't popping up.  The "Enter how much $" pane just refreshes until you enter a number greater than 0.  The second pane is popping up if I use a negative number though.Messing with the code to get that to happen.

Comment: Got it, put a <= in the second if statement.

Answer (score 0):

null is not 0. and != is not <=. also, you're getting back a string. you'll only know which number it was after you parsed it. only then can you decide.

Comment: thank you.  I put the if statement after the parse and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've covered `booleans` in class yet, but I'd do something like this:

```
boolean isGood;
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter how much money you can save annually.");  
 if(result != null)
 {
   saveAmount = Double.parseDouble(result);
   if (saveAmount > 0) 
   {
     isGood = true;
   } 
     else
   {
     isGood = false;
   }
 }
   else
 {
    isGood = false;
 }
 if (isGood == false)
 {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pick a number greater than 0!");
 }
```

That's not how I'd actually write it--I'd compress the first part to

```
isGood = saveAmount > 0;
```

which sets `isGood` to either `true` or `false` in one line;  and instead of `isGood == false` I'd write

```
if (!isGood)
```

but I'm trying to stick to simpler concepts.

I don't have enough information to tell why you're getting a "bad operand types" error.